# Search for Matching Properties and Equivalent Property Values

Tags: javascript, loops, object, properties

I am working on a task for freecodecamp and find myself very stuck. The task is to:

"Make a function that looks through a list (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have equivalent property values (second argument).

Here are some helpful topics:

Global Object

Object.hasOwnProperty()

Object.keys()"

Here is what I have so far. I was hoping for some guidance and explanation not just a completely different code to copy and paste. Looking to learn and grow. Thank you so much.

```
function where(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];

  var sourceProp = Object.keys(source)[1];

  for (i = 0; i<collection.length; i++){
    if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(sourceProp) && collection.sourceProp == source.sourceProp){
       arr.push(collection[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

where([{ first: 'Romeo', last: 'Montague' }, { first: 'Mercutio', last: null }, { first: 'Tybalt', last: 'Capulet' }], { last: 'Capulet' });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some typo mistakes in your code. See comments below:

**[a]** `Object.keys()` returns you an array of the property keys. To take the first and the only key, you should use [0], not [1].

**[b]** In your condition of if statement, you have to refer to the value of the i-th element by `collection[i][sourceProp]` where `sourceProp` is the key you took from step [a]. See "why" at the bottom of my answer.

**[c]** To take the value of `source` argument, you can use `source[sourceProp]` to access it.

```
function where(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];

  var sourceProp = Object.keys(source)[0]; // Take the first key, index=0

  for (i = 0; i<collection.length; i++){
    // Use collection[i][sourceProp] to take the value
    if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(sourceProp) && collection[i][sourceProp] == source[sourceProp]){
       arr.push(collection[i]);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

**NOTE:** You incorrectly use dot notation to access the object's value.
When you access a variable with:

```
source.sourceProp
```

It refers to the property `sourceProp` of `source` which is not what you meant to do. To access a property with variable name, use [] notation and pass your variable in:

```
source[sourceProp]
```

Comment: This is a great answer with a great explanation. Thank you. I am glad that my approach was pretty close just some easy to correct mistakes.